# Accessing a dynamic dictionary key in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the below python dictionary (dict1) where I can access the value in this way:

```
dict1['starters]['Chicken Biryani Type']['Please select']
```

The keys 'Chicken Biryani Type' and 'Please Select' are dynamically generated. How would I access these in that scenario because as I understand I can't use an index.

Dictionary (Dict1)

```
{
    'starters': {
        'product_name': 'Papadam',
        'base_price': 3.0,
        'Chicken Biryani Type': {
            'Please select': [{
                'Chicken': 3.0
            }, {
                'Puree': 4.0
            }],
            'Please remove': [{
                'mayonnaise': 0.0
            }, {
                'ketchup': 0.0
            }]
        },
        'Papadam Type': {
            'Plain or Spicy': [{
                'Plain': 3.0
            }, {
                'Spicy': 5.0
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

---

UPDATED. How the dictionary is created:

```
dict1 = {}
for cat in category_list:
    cat_dic = {cat: {}}
    dict1.update(cat_dic)
    sliced_df2 = df[df.productCategoryName == cat ]
    product_type = sliced_df2.productTypeName.unique()
    for ptype in product_type:
        sliced_df3 = sliced_df2[sliced_df2.productTypeName == ptype ]
        product_name = sliced_df3.productName.unique()
        product_name_a = {"product_name": product_name[0]}
        base_price = {"base_price": sliced_df3['variant_price'].min()}
        dict1[cat].update(product_name_a)
        dict1[cat].update(base_price)

        product_type_dict = {ptype: {}}
        dict1[cat].update(product_type_dict)
        attribute_names = sliced_df3.attribute_name.unique()
        for item in attribute_names:
            attribute_dict = {item: []}
            dict1[cat][ptype].update(attribute_dict)
            sliced_df4 = sliced_df3[sliced_df3.attribute_name == item ]
            # for item in attribute_values:
            for index, row in sliced_df4.iterrows():
                ab = {row['attribute_value']: row['variant_price']}
                dict1[cat][ptype][item].append(ab)
```

Comment: Just edited the question to show how dict1 is generated

Comment: You can also loop over keys/values/both with the construct `for [key | value | key, value] in dictionary.[keys() | values() | items()]`

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is the desired logic to select keys, e.g. to decide between ``Chicken Biryani Type`` and ``Papadam Typ``?

Comment: How do I access the dynamically generated key if I don't know what its called?

Comment: can you please add why you need to access dynamically generated  key.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I will be looping over the dictionary to return the values

Comment: @Rutnet Is your goal then to get the keys, or get the keys to get the values? Are you aware that you can get the values without knowing the keys? Are you aware that you can get all keys with their values?